# JPA Select Query not working in SpringBoot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to implement query for to check if custom filed(Non-primary key filed) is exists or not in MySQL Database.

## Query is below:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT case when count(p)> 0 then true else false end FROM PEOPLE p WHERE p.number = :number", nativeQuery = true)
```

getting error:

SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22/ Unknown column 'p' in 'field list'

I have implemented above query by following this url- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-exists-query as reference.

Can anyone please check and help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In your query snippet, `from`  seems to be duplicated (`from FROM`).

Comment: thanks for identifying that but still getting error - `SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22/ Unknown column 'p' in 'field list'`..please check @premysl

Answer (score 0):

You are using a native query, not JPQL, use

`count(*)`